# Load and cache script from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

In my project I need to load a very big .js file from javascript and cache it.

I wanted to load the script file from the login page, and then in all other page to put the script in normal tag like this `<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>`

The fact is that, I tried 3 different methods, but in each one the file is not cached and if I change page, from login to another, the browser download it again.

In the first method i created an element with javascript and then i added this element to my page:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
// Fire the loading
head.appendChild(script);
```

In the second, I used jQuery's `getScript`:

```
$.getScript('assets/js/app.js',function(){
    alert('OK');
});
```

And in the third i tried with an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "assets/js/app.js",
    success: function(){},
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true
});
```

But no one of these methods seems to caching the scripts.
Is there a method to obtain that?

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem. The first method worked. I forgot that I had the "disable cache" checked in the chrome's debug settings. 
(I tried with IE11, Firefox, Edge and Chrome)

Comment: why dont you store the file in localstorage or sessionstorage and clear it when required .

Comment: well getScript uses cache breaking out of the box. The JS one should read from the cache. Are the proper cache headers being set for your files? Are your debugging tools set up to not cache any files [they have that setting]?

Comment: _"and then in all other page"_ Do you mean separate `html` documents?, which may not be already loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You don't share much information about your project.
I found a page where they explain how to speed up js loading by compressing and caching your js files, take a look, you may find it useful

https://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/